# Submit a form with a collection of a Model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a ViewModel which contains a collection of type of my Model, like so:

```
public class OrderConfirm
{
    public ICollection<QuoteLine> SalesLines { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public int EnquiryID { get; set; }
}
```

My QuoteLine Model looks like so:

```
public class QuoteLine
{
    public int QuoteLineId { get; set; }
    public int LostReasonId { get; set; }
    public virtual LostReason LostReason { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

In my View, I then Iterate through each of these QuoteLines, within a form, like so:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ConfirmLostOrder", new AjaxOptions()
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "LostOrders",
    OnBegin = "LostOrderConfirm"
}))
    {
        <table class="completed-enq-table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Item Number
                </th>
                <th>
                    Reason
                </th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var sales in Model.SalesLines)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@sales.ItemName
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => sales.QuoteLineID)
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => sales.LostReasonId, ((IEnumerable<myApp.Models.LostReason>)ViewBag.LostReasons).Select(option => new SelectListItem
       {
           Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.LostReason),
           Value = option.LostReasonId.ToString(),
           Selected = (Model != null) && (option.LostReasonId == sales.LostStatusId)
       }))
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <input type="submit" style="float: right;" value="Submit Lost Order" />
    }
```

Then my `HttpPost` action looks like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConfirmLostOrder(List<QuoteLine> models)
{   
    // process order
    return PartialView("Sales/_ConfirmLostOrder");
}
```

The problem is, `models` is null. If I use a `FormCollection` I can see each of the values submitted but I'd like to use my model and not a FormCollection as I'd like to process and edit each of the line submitted individually as they may have different reason's

Comment: What is the type of your model in that view? Is it OrderConfirm?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have said that!

Comment: Can you try "public ActionResult ConfirmLostOrder(OrderConfirm model)" and then access each QuoteLine from model.SalesLine?

Comment: I did before but the values were all null, Currency null, EnquiryId 0, SalesLines null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a `foreach` in this instance, it needs to be a `for` loop so that the `name` attributes of the fields contain the correct index so that default model binding knows it's binding to a list.

**Firstly, I'm going to move your dropdown values out of the `ViewBag` (they should really be in there). That'll also take out some of that *nasty* logic in your view :)**

So your model is now:

```
public class OrderConfirm
{
    public List<QuoteLine> SalesLines { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public int EnquiryID { get; set; }
    public SelectList LostReasons { get; set; }
}
```

Try this instead of your `foreach`:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.SalesLines.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Model.SalesLines[i].ItemName
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SalesLines[i].QuoteLineId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SalesLines[i].ItemName) //assuming you want this
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SalesLines[i].LostReasonId, Model.LostReasons)
       </td>
   </tr>
}
```

Then change your post method to take your `OrderConfirm` model type:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConfirmLostOrder(OrderConfirm model)
```

Comment: I get: `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<myApp.Models.QuoteLine>'`

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff Ah, can you not change it to a `List`?

Comment: Excellent! This seems to work! Thanks a lot, I moved that Viewbag to my ViewModel too!

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff No problems! Glad I could help :). Yeah that's better practice to do that! :)